# How does Plex Server Work with MyPlex?

Tags: networking, media-center

I had a little scary surprise the other day when I tried out Plex as a media solutions.

I installed the server on my local server that is behind the router and windows firewall. All ports are blocked on the router and I have private stuff on this machine. After installing the plex server and I logged in to myplex from the server and then selected the server from my mobile phone by logging into myplex there also.

I understand that this is what must be the best user experience from most people, it just worked :) But how did this happen, because from my knowing my pc should not be accessible from outside my network. Is all my media send to myplex and my devices streaming from there or how can they make this work?

I am concerned that if someday myplex is compromised and some hacker get access to my myplex credentials, then he basicly have access to my media collection, and I could potential be streaming content that I have no rights for streaming to anyone but my self?

Same as I have no interest in myplex having a list of the content my server is holding like private home videos.

I have deleted my myplex account and would like to know if myplex is just not the solution for me? Can I use it without myplex? In the windows 8 phone app, I am having a hard time to connect to my server without myplex atleast and also in the myplex server I have a hard time figuring out where to set the port for it to listhen on.

I only want my server to be visible to me and no one else, should I consider alternative solutions? And at the end to the plex community, I think you should address this better when installing and making it clear when I press stuff in the configuration that I am making content available outside my private network.

Comment: It sounds like it might be using UPNP. The Plex wiki - http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/MyPlex - might be of some help to you regarding security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have the same kind of experience.

I would love to use Plex, but do not trust anyone but myself to manage the security of my own server and media. If you like to use plex without using the myPlex account you can only make a VPN connection to your home LAN. Plex thinks you are a local machine and does not require a myPlex account.
Still i do block all traffic to plex's ip's manually with my ISP firewall. And to be sure blocked de plex application in my local firewall to just be able to contact local area ip's.

I do love the power of the transcoding and presentation of my movies. But sharing all this information with any company (even plex) is no option in my opinion.

Alternative: buy a fiber isp and use FTP to share and XBMC to play over the internet.

I hope Plex will release a stealth edition with only local usernames and password to access my media. So i can manage them myself and restrict it by IP on my modem..

Comment: Forgot your question,
If your pc can access internet, Plex server is able to use this to setup a connection with MyPLEX. The firewall is used to block connections from the internet to your local machine. But because your local plex server is establishing this connection it goes right true your firewall.

Comment: Thanks. Ye I vote for being able to use it with local usernames also. Good point about blocking the plex ips. I will do just that.